# How to read an inputstream and do other things at the same time?

Tags: java, inputstream

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
while (0==0) {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(cmdsin,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    br.lines().forEach(line -> System.out.println("CMD: " + line));
    System.out.println("this never runs");
    InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(datain,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);
    br2.lines().forEach(line2 -> System.out.println("DATA: " + line2));
}
```

I need to read both input streams as well as run some other code. But, the code gets stuck doing the forEach thing even when there is nothing to read. How do I get it unstuck so I can read the other stream and continue with the loop?

All the methods I've found for reading input streams ended with this same problem; I've seen this solution works the best so far (I can actually get the data from the first stream, at least) and someone had said it was faster, so I decided to use this method.

Comment: Why do you have an infinite while loop?

Comment: @Konrad so I have an infinite loop, I need it. I can clean my code and create the inputstreamreaders and stuff outside the loop later, I just need a solution for this specific part

Comment: You need to explain what you expect as the question makes no sense. The only way the forEach will end will be if the stream ends. So if the stream does not end (perhaps System.in) you won't exit the loop, and if the stream does end then stream won't work for the next iteration. If you need to read streams independently use a thread per stream.

Comment: @DuncG Is it impossible to just read a stream until there's nothing left to read, then continue executing code afterwards? I just want to be able to read the contents of the stream, print it out, then do the same thing for the next stream.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough context to understand the problem as @DuncG said. What are the sources of those streams? A string, a socket, standard input? What do they contain?

Comment: @aled I'm reading from a TCP port. It should just be normal characters.

Comment: Characters are meaningless for this issue. A socket just doesn't has an end.

Comment: It's basically impossible to do what you want without threads or other more complicated mechanisms like event based IO. `br.lines()` tries to read the stream until the stream signals it has ended. That will never happen for a stream from a tcp connection unless the connection closes. If you know that there's one line from each reader you can use `readline()` then read from the other stream. If you don't know which stream to wait on use 2 threads each processing the input line by line using readline - or in case this is some text based server you can switch to a framework like https://netty.io/

Comment: Some types of InputStream may support `available()` to tell you what you can read without blocking. But I suggest you don't use that call though, and put details on what you are really trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I will just use more than one thread, seems to be the only option.

Comment: Each thread may have the same issue and remain executing without finishing.

Comment: @aled that's what i'm expecting, I'll just have a thread dedicated for each stream I'm reading from

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading from a socket, there is no end of file like when reading a file. The input stream will be open for as long as the socket will be open. There are some ways to indicate when the input stream should be closed:

- You implement an application level communication protocol in which the data indicate when the input ends. For example you can send the length of the message as part of the data, or in a header, or some end record or text that you need to scan for to indicate the end. For example HTTP can send the full length in a header or in chunked mode sends a character sequence to indicate the end.
- The server closes the socket. However if the server never closes the socket you'll have the same problem.
- You set a read timeout. If the server delays to send the data for above the timeout the application may close the socket prematurely.
- Just leave the socket open. If the communication is expected to be persistent you may have to assume that the data may never finish. You have some option, like interleave readings of different streams or use different threads. You may have to handle reconnections for long-lived sockets. You can not assume that the network connections are not going to be interrupted at some point.

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` will continue reading from `InputStream` as long as the stream is open.

Your code will stay stuck until `InputStream` gets closed by the data source you are reading from, or until you close it yourself from a different `Thread` in your application by calling `cmdin.close()`.

If you simply wanna read whatever is available on the `InputStream` at the moment, you can do something along the lines of:

```
var buffer = new byte[cmdsin.available()];
cmdsin.read(buffer);
cmdsin.close();

var lines = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).lines();
lines.forEach(line -> System.out.println("CMD: " + line));
```

Note that `String#lines` is only availble from Java 11.